# Add className dynamically to classbased component

Tags: reactjs

I am rendering a class based component `<LiveChat customClassName="live-chat-wrapper" />`.  As you can see I am sending `customClassName` as a prop to the LiveChat component. LiveChat component returns -
`<div className={"chat-box " + this.props.customClassName}>CHAT</div>`
It is working perfectly, but If I don't send `customClassName` as a prop to the LiveChat (rendering only `<LiveChat />`) then it is adding undefined in place of `this.props.customClassName`.

**I want to stop showing undefined, If I don't send any customClassName as a prop.** How to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use template literals to achieve it.

```
<div className={`chat-box ${this.props.customClassName || ''}`}>CHAT</div>
```